# Terraform error: error creating route: InvalidEgressOnlyInternetGatewayId.Malformed

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws

I started a new chapter in my life, and this world of IaC (Infrastructure as code) is really amazing...

I saw a free course in YouTube, how to start working with Terraform in AWS, but something along the way is not working properly, although the code seems the as in the videos, and mine.

here is the code, and the result.
I'll be grateful for your assistance in understanding what is wrong.

## Terraform details:

Terraform v0.14.10

- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.36.0

  ## The code:

  ## 3. Create Custom Route Table

```
    resource "aws_route_table" "prod-route-table" {
      vpc_id = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id
    
      route {
        cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
        gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
      }
    
      route {
        ipv6_cidr_block        = "::/0"
        egress_only_gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
      }
    
      tags = {
        Name = "example"
      }
    }
```

## 4. Create a Subnet

```
    resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_1" {
      vpc_id            = aws_vpc.prod-vpc.id
      cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
      availability_zone = "us-east-1e"
    
      tags = {
        "name" = "Prod-subnet"
      }
    }
```

## 5. Assosicate subent with Route Table

```
    resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
    
      subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet_1.id
      route_table_id = aws_route_table.prod-route-table.id
    
    }
```

## The error:

```
    Error: error creating route: InvalidEgressOnlyInternetGatewayId.Malformed: Invalid id: "igw-07f6dac9f8bd89fd5" (expecting "eigw-...")
            status code: 400, request id: 7f7e2445-f537-4113-a52e-ac6b32dee888
    
      on main.tf line 26, in resource "aws_route_table" "prod-route-table":
      26: resource "aws_route_table" "prod-route-table" {
```

I added only the part of the code that the error is pointing me too.

Answer (score 5):

You don't show the code for how you create the `aws_internet_gateway.gw` resource but the issue is that this resource is a normal Internet Gateway but you are passing the value to the `egress_only_gateway_id` field under which is expecting an ID for an egress only internet gateway.

The solution would be to either update the `aws_internet_gateway` resource to be an `aws_egress_only_internet_gateway` resource or to update the `route` property to be `gateway_id` which expects a normal Internet gateway ID and not an egress only gateway.

If you are just starting out with this stuff, I would avoid egress only internet gateways for now.

Comment: thanks for the reply.

The code came from a course online, i followed the course step by step.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLB_c_ayRMo&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org

I pasted the full code here, but i had some issues to upload it.
if you would like to see the full code you can click the link i attached, and see everything.

Comment: rewatch the video, around 1:39:00 he runs into the same error above and fixes it in the way that I described